# Source Directory MSVC

Tags: xcode, visual-c++, project

argh, this should be an easy one. How can I set the directory that a MSVC project uses to store source files? I wish to use a directory outside the project dir, As this is a multiplatform project which will also have an xcode directory.

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a per-project setting for this. What however works in any IDE i've encountered, including MSVC and Xcode, is to simply use the *"Add existing file(s)"* features and just create them where they are supposed to be before-hand.